# Macro working over a whole word (plain TeX)

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex

I have spend a good time searching in references and forums for a answer to the question I'm raising here.

I would like to write a macro that gets a word as a parameter without needing to using braces informing this. It would be a smart macro that recognizes what should be a component of a parameter, constructing it token by token until finding a not proper candidate (that will be replaced intact after finishing the macro itself). For examples

```
\def\km#1{% definition: only accept numbers: writes the unit after the subsequent integer word (parameter)%}
\def\mathstyle#1{% definition: accept anything except point and space: put parameter in mathmode (assumes that is called in "text mode" for simplification)%}
% usage
The radius of the Earth is about \km 6300. %%
%% *\km 6300.* expands to 6300 $km$.
The distance between \mathstyle Point-A to \mathstyle Point-B is \km 20 assume that the Earth is plain.
%% puts Point-A and Point-B between math shifts
```

In short, in order to achieve this, supposedly, I need to check the characters one by one and recalling a handling macro until a not recognizable token is taken by it.

**The problem is**: in many cases TeX ignores spaces after a macro. So, I wasn't able to create a macro that handles with spaces (concatenating all words separated by spaces).

How can I fix? How to now destroy a space after a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand the question (the "How to now destroy a space after a macro?" question seems unrelated to the context above, perhaps an example would be instructive). To answer getting single words as parameters, you can scan token by token using `\futurelet` and test if a letter appears

```
\protected\def\getword#1{%
    \begingroup \toks0{}\toks1{#1}%
    \futurelet\next\getwordA
}
\def\getwordA{\ifcat A\noexpand\next \expandafter\getwordB \else \expandafter\getwordC \fi}
\def\getwordB#1{\toks0\expandafter{\the\toks0 #1}\futurelet\next\getwordA}
\def\getwordC{\edef\tmp{\endgroup \the\toks1{\the\toks0}}\tmp}

\def\textbf#1{{\bf#1}} \def\textit#1{{\it#1\/}} % demo

\getword\textbf Foo bar
{\getword\textit baz} fu

\bye
```

It is easy to allow dashes, underscores, etc by adding a few extra checks.

[image: output]

Comment: There is some TeXian trick in "\ifcat ...\noexpand", but I can't figure out. Am I wrong?

Comment: `\ifcat` expands everything in the way and compares the next two unexpandable tokens, this can cause unexpected problems if `\next` had been some macro.

Comment: I've just read in The TeX Book something about it (page 209). Thank you too much for completing my lecture. But... **\ifcat A\noexpand\next** should "return" FALSE (assuming \catcode`\A=11), once \next has catcode = 16 (to \ifcat evaluation), isn't it?

Comment: Implicit tokens (those produced by `\let` or `\futurelet`) are an exception. For example `\if{\bgroup` (where `\bgroup` is defined via `\let\bgroup= {`) is true .

Comment: TeX never gets tired of playing weird pranks with me... A peculiar case for all commands (with some exceptions!)

Answer (score 3):

There are pathological cases that need to be tested for, such as how to handle a decimal point in `\km`.  Fortunately, logic can be built into a token cycle, and `tokcycle` can be invoked from plain tex.

```
\input tokcycle.tex
\def\aborttoks{\tcpush{\empty\endtokcycraw}}
\newif\ifdotless
\xtokcycleenvironment\km
 {\tctestifnum{`##1<`0}{%
  \ifdotless\ifx.##1\addcytoks{##1}\dotlessfalse
  \else\aborttoks\fi\else\tcpush{##1}\aborttoks\fi}{%
  \tctestifnum{`##1>`9}{\aborttoks}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
 {\tcpushgroup{##1}\aborttoks}
 {\tcpush{##1}\aborttoks}
 {\tcpush{##1}\aborttoks}
 {\dotlesstrue}
 {\addcytoks{\kern2pt km}}

Testing \km3., \km 4000 and \km 2.3. Next sentence.

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can use e-TeX extension (that is, `pdftex`), you can exploit `expl3`.

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathstyle
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nnF
   { (.*?)(\.|\s) } % search anything up to a period or space
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\1\cE\}\2 } % replace with \ensuremath{<tokens>}<period or space>
   {} % do nothing if no match
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \km
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nnF
   { ([[:digit:]]*) } 
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\1\c{kilometers}\cE\} } % replace
   {} % do nothing if no match
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ensuremath #1
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { #1 } { $#1$ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \kilometers { \,\rm km }

\ExplSyntaxOff

The distance between \mathstyle {\rm Point-}A to $\mathstyle {\rm Point-}B$ is \km 20, assume 
that the Earth is plain and no wider than $\km 100000$.

\bye
```

As you see, the macros work both in text and in math mode.

[image]