# Test if an argument starts with a particular string

Tags: macros, conditionals, strings

Is there a way in tex to test if an argument starts with some string or not?
And then extract the text that follows that start?

As an example, I want to define a command that makes a text bold if it starts with `my` and italic otherwise.

```tex
\transform{my big world}
% Returns "\textbf{big world}". 

\transform{our small world}
% Returns "\textit{small world}". 

\transform{your world}
% Returns \textit{world}

% It would be great if the test is case insensitive 
\transform{My world} 
% Returns \textbf{world}
```

If possible, I prefer a method not using expl3 (I don't understand it enough to tinker with it).

The answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100209/gobbling-an-argument-if-it-starts-with) gobbles a single character, which I can use for every character of my string. But that would get unwieldy rather quickly for long strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your first word is always separated from the rest by a space, you can do with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{\transform@#1\@nil}
\def\transform@@prefix{my}
\def\transform@#1 #2\@nil{%
  \lowercase{\def\transform@@start{#1}}%
  \ifx\transform@@start\transform@@prefix
    \textbf{#2}%
  \else
    \textit{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\transform{my big world} should return \textbf{big world}.

\transform{our small world} should return \textit{small world}.

\transform{your world} should return \textit{world}

\transform{My world} should return \textbf{world}

\end{document}
```

The first word is isolated and its lowercase version is matched with `my`.

[image]

Since you want a colon, rather than a space, it's possible to manage the absence of a prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{\transform@#1::\@nil}
\def\transform@@prefix{my}
\def\transform@#1:#2:#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    % no colon in #1
    \textit{#1}%
  \else
    \lowercase{\def\transform@@start{#1}}%
      \ifx\transform@@start\transform@@prefix
        \textbf{#2}%
      \else
        \textit{#2}%
      \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\transform{my:big world} should return \textbf{big world}.

\transform{our:small world} should return \textit{small world}.

\transform{your:world} should return \textit{world}

\transform{My:world} should return \textbf{world}

\transform{world} should return \textit{world}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An `expl3` version, which is also (almost) fully expandable (it is not really because of `\textit` and `\textbf`, but we can use `\text_expand:n` to take care of that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% just for the final test
\cs_new_eq:NN \textexpand \text_expand:n
%%%

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\transform}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tohiko_transform:V #2
   }
   {
    \tohiko_transform:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npx \tohiko_transform:n #1
 {% colons are special in expl3
  \exp_not:N \__tohiko_transform:w #1 \c_colon_str \c_colon_str \exp_not:N \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tohiko_transform:n { V }

\use:x
 {% colons are special in expl3
  \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__tohiko_transform:w 
    ##1 \c_colon_str ##2 \c_colon_str ##3 \exp_not:N \q_stop
 }
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \__tohiko_transformed:Nn \textit { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__tohiko_transform:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__tohiko_transform:nn #1 #2
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_lowercase:n { #1 } } { my }
   {
    \__tohiko_transformed:Nn \textbf { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__tohiko_transformed:Nn \textit { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__tohiko_transformed:Nn #1 #2
 {
  #1{\tl_trim_spaces:n{#2}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\testA}{my:hello world}
\newcommand{\testB}{our:hello world}

\begin{document}

\transform{my: big world} should return \textbf{big world}.

\transform{our:small world} should return \textit{small world}.

\transform{your:world } should return \textit{world}.

\transform{My:world} should return \textbf{world}.

\transform{world} should return \textit{world}.

\transform*{\testA} should return \textbf{hello world}.

\transform*{\testB} should return \textit{hello world}.

\edef\test{\textexpand{\transform{my: big world}}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\edef\test{\textexpand{\transform*{\testB}}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, the separator character is a colon but this solution can be adapted easily to that case. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be difficult to adapt it so that if no space is found, the whole is italicized? So that `\transform{world}` changes to `\textit{world}`?

Comment: @Tohiko With the colon it's easier; with spaces it would be more complicated. I added the code.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out that to `\transform` accept a command which evaluates to a string I also need to define `\newcommand{\transform}[1]{\expandafter\transform@#1::\@nil}`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It recognizes both `:` and whitespace as possible delimiters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function transform ( s )
  if s:find ( "^[Mm]y" ) then
    s = s:gsub  ( "^.-[%s:]+(.*)" , "\\textbf{%1}")
  elseif s:find ( "^.-[%s:]+" ) then
    s = s:gsub  ( "^.-[%s:]+(.*)" , "\\textit{%1}") 
  else
    s = "\\textit{"..s.."}"
  end
  tex.sprint ( s )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\transform[1]{\directlua{transform(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\transform{my:big world}   should return \textbf{big world}.
\transform{my   big world} should return \textbf{big world}.
\transform{my: big world}  should return \textbf{big world}.

\smallskip
\transform{My:big world}   should return \textbf{big world}.
\transform{My   big world} should return \textbf{big world}.
\transform{My: big world}  should return \textbf{big world}.

\smallskip
\transform{our:big world}   should return \textit{big world}.
\transform{our big world}   should return \textit{big world}.
\transform{our:  big world} should return \textit{big world}.

\smallskip
\transform{world} should return \textit{world}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not using expl3 I can offer a generic mechanism `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` for detecting whether a macro argument's leading tokens form a specific token-sequence.

`\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` requires an *⟨internal token-check-macro⟩* that processes a macro-argument delimited by that specific token-sequence.

The fact that the specific token-sequence is used as an argument-delimiter implies that the specific token-sequence cannot contain explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group) or 2(end group) or 6(parameter).

Syntax is:

```
\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{⟨argument which is to be checked⟩}%
                              {⟨a ⟨token sequence⟩ without explicit 
                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
                                or 6⟩}%
                              {⟨internal token-check-macro⟩}%
                              {⟨tokens to be delivered in case
                                ⟨argument which is to be checked⟩ has
                                ⟨token sequence⟩ as leading tokens⟩}%
                              {⟨tokens to be delivered in case 
                                ⟨argument which is to be checked⟩
                                does not have ⟨token sequence⟩ as
                                leading tokens⟩}%
```

For defining the *⟨internal token-check-macro⟩* with the delimited argument you can use

```
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{⟨internal token-check-macro⟩}%
                             {⟨token-sequence-gobble-macro⟩}%
                             {⟨token sequence⟩}%
```

*⟨token-sequence-gobble-macro⟩* is not used by `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` but it can be used for gobbling the leading token-sequence.

Here is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter    
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@stopromannumeral,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category 1 or 2 or 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
%%                                or 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{\relax}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token-sequence-gobble-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% - Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%%   until reaching <token sequence> and spit that out,
%%   nested in braces. <token sequence> is discarded.
%% - Defines <token-sequence-gobble-macro> to gobble/discard
%%   everything until reaching <token sequence>.
%%   <token sequence> is discarded, too.
%% <token sequence> must not contain explicit character tokens
%% of category 1 or 2 or 6.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#3{{##1}}}%
  \@ifdefinable#2{\def#2#3{}}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@Checkmyspace}{\UD@Gobblemyspace}{my }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMyspace}{\UD@GobbleMyspace}{My }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckmYspace}{\UD@GobblemYspace}{mY }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMYspace}{\UD@GobbleMYspace}{MY }%
%\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@Checkmy}{\UD@Gobblemy}{my}%
%\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMy}{\UD@GobbleMy}{My}%
%\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckmY}{\UD@GobblemY}{mY}%
%\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMY}{\UD@GobbleMY}{MY}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletospace{\long\def\UD@gobbletospace#1 {}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoSpace[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletospace#1 }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\transform[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{my }{\UD@Checkmyspace}{\textbf{\UD@Gobblemyspace#1}}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{My }{\UD@CheckMyspace}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMyspace#1}}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{mY }{\UD@CheckmYspace}{\textbf{\UD@GobblemYspace#1}}{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{MY }{\UD@CheckMYspace}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMYspace#1}}{%
%          \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{my }{\UD@Checkmy}{\textbf{\UD@Gobblemy#1}}{%
%            \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{My }{\UD@CheckMy}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMy#1}}{%
%              \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{mY }{\UD@CheckmY}{\textbf{\UD@GobblemY#1}}{%
%                \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{MY }{\UD@CheckMY}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMY#1}}{%
                  \textit{\UD@CheckWhetherNoSpace{#1}{}{\UD@gobbletospace}#1}%
%                }%
%              }%
%            }%
%          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\transform{my big world}|: \transform{my big world}

\verb|\transform{our small world}|: \transform{our small world}

\verb|\transform{your world}|: \transform{your world}

\verb|\transform{My world}|: \transform{My world}

\verb|\transform{My }|: \transform{My }

\verb|\transform{My}|: \transform{My}

\verb|\transform{Bla}|: \transform{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You did not specify desired behavior in case the argument contains no spaces. In this case the argument is delivered in `\textit` without anything being removed.

If you need different behavior let me know via a comment and I will edit my answer accordingly.

**`\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` does not change the letter-casing of any component of its first argument and thus `\transform` does not change the letter-casing of any component of its argument.**

Occurrence of marker-tokens/sentinel-tokens like `\@nil` within the argument of `\transform`/within the first argument of `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` is not forbidden.

Unmatched `\if..` or `\else` or `\or` or `\fi` or `\csname` or `\endcsname` may occur within the first argument of `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens`. However with `\transform` things are passed on to the LaTeX 2ε-kernel-macros`\textit`/`\textbf` which don't handle such unmatched things.

**`\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` and thus `\transform` itself work by means of expansion only.** This means carrying out any of the macros belonging to the mechanism for finding out whether the argument has a leading token-sequence `my⟨space⟩`/`My⟨space⟩`
/`mY⟨space⟩`
/`MY⟨space⟩` does not trigger performing whatsoever temporary assignment.
`\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens` can be used with things like `\edef`, `\expanded`, `\write`, `\message`, `\csname..\endcsname`, `\number`, `\romannumeral`, `\ifcsname..\endcsname`, `\numexpr` etc as well.

However, the LaTeX 2ε-kernel-macros `\textbf` and `\textit` themselves are not fully expandable and cannot reliably be used with such things. With `\textbf` and `\textit` both the LaTeX 2ε-kernel's `\protect`-mechanism and the TeX-engine's `protected`-mechanism and with old LaTeX 2ε-kernels not applying any protection-mechanism to `\textbf` and `\textit` at all will at least disturb things like `\csname..\endcsname`, `\number`, `\romannumeral` `\ifcsname..\endcsname`,  and `\numexpr`.

---

---

You can easily adapt this to using colon (`:`) instad of space but be aware that there are packages which turn the colon into an active character while the mechanism below is defined while the category code of `:` is 12(other).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter    
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@stopromannumeral,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category 1 or 2 or 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
%%                                or 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{\relax}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token-sequence-gobble-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% - Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%%   until reaching <token sequence> and spit that out,
%%   nested in braces. <token sequence> is discarded.
%% - Defines <token-sequence-gobble-macro> to gobble/discard
%%   everything until reaching <token sequence>.
%%   <token sequence> is discarded, too.
%% <token sequence> must not contain explicit character tokens
%% of category 1 or 2 or 6.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#3{{##1}}}%
  \@ifdefinable#2{\def#2#3{}}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@Checkmycolon}{\UD@Gobblemycolon}{my:}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMycolon}{\UD@GobbleMycolon}{My:}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckmYcolon}{\UD@GobblemYcolon}{mY:}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckMYcolon}{\UD@GobbleMYcolon}{MY:}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletocolon{\long\def\UD@gobbletocolon#1:{}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoColon[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletocolon#1:}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\transform[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{my:}{\UD@Checkmycolon}{\textbf{\UD@Gobblemycolon#1}}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{My:}{\UD@CheckMycolon}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMycolon#1}}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{mY:}{\UD@CheckmYcolon}{\textbf{\UD@GobblemYcolon#1}}{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{MY:}{\UD@CheckMYcolon}{\textbf{\UD@GobbleMYcolon#1}}{%
          \textit{\UD@CheckWhetherNoColon{#1}{}{\UD@gobbletocolon}#1}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\transform{my:big world}| yields \transform{my:big world}

\verb|\transform{our:small world}| yields \transform{our:small world}

\verb|\transform{your:world}| yields \transform{your:world}

\verb|\transform{My:world}| yields \transform{My:world}

\verb|\transform{My:}| yields \transform{My:}

\verb|\transform{My}| yields \transform{My}

\verb|\transform{Bla}| yields \transform{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For completeness an `xstring` solution. First lower case the argument, then find the first space (default 0 if no space is present), split in left and right part (left part empty if no space is present), compare the left part to `my`  (including the space), print the right part in bold or italics accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{%
\lowercase{\def\arglc{#1}}%
\StrPosition{\arglc}{ }[\spacepos]%
\StrSplit{\arglc}{\spacepos}{\leftpart}{\rightpart}%
\IfEq{\leftpart}{my }{\textbf{\rightpart}}{\textit{\rightpart}}%
}
\begin{document}
\transform{my big world}
% Returns "\textbf{big world}". 

\transform{our small world}
% Returns "\textit{small world}". 

\transform{your world}
% Returns \textit{world}

% It would be great if the test is case insensitive 
\transform{My world} 
% Returns \textbf{world}

\transform{world}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `\getword` macro from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616582/) would work well too.

```
\documentclass{article}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616582/
    \protected\def\getword#1{%
        \begingroup \toks0{}\toks1{#1}%
        \futurelet\next\getwordA
    }
    \def\getwordA{\ifcat A\noexpand\next \expandafter\getwordB \else \expandafter\getwordC \fi}
    \def\getwordB#1{\toks0\expandafter{\the\toks0 #1}\futurelet\next\getwordA}
    \def\getwordC{\edef\tmp{\endgroup \the\toks1{\the\toks0}}\tmp}

\def\transformA#1{%
    \lowercase{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{my}=0 \bfseries
        \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{our}=0 \itshape \fi\fi}%
    \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand\transform[1]{\begingroup \getword\transformA#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}

    \transform{my big world}

    \transform{our small world}

    \transform{your world}

    \transform{My world}

    \transform{} \transform{\relax} % nothing

\end{document}
```

[image: output]